# Cast to generic subclass in Java

Tags: java, generics, casting

I want to write universal function, which can make an object of any type by name and return it as its own type, not as Object type.

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
public class Test{
    static <T extends Object> T makeObject(String className) {
        try {
            Class<?> c = Class.forName(className);
            Constructor<?> constructor = c.getConstructor();
            Object object = constructor.newInstance();
            return (T)c.cast(object);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         //without casting
         String obj = makeObject("java.lang.String");
         System.out.println(obj.getClass());
    }
}
```

It works fine, but I get the warning

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from capture#4-of ? to T
```

What to do to fix the problem without adding `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`?

Comment: May be, thank you. But I don't understand what to change in my program. I guess IU need to change line `Class<?> c = Class.forName(className);` but which way?

Comment: There is no way that you can avoid the `@SuppressWarnings`. You *are* doing something unsafe - you're casting to `(T)` without knowing at all that the class is actually an instance of `T` - and since the method doesn't even know what T is, the cast doesn't actually do anything. `c.cast(` is pretty pointless since you just invoked the constructor of `c` - `(T) object` is good enough.

Comment: As-is there is no possibility to fix the warning. This is due to the fact that [generics are erased](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). The only workaround is to pass the class object directly as an argument. [`List.toArray(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#toArray(T%5B%5D)) uses a similar solution by providing an array of the expected type.

Comment: Pass the class Object as an argument where to?

Answer (score 6):

If you want this to be safe you need to pass the class as a parameter, otherwise there is no way you're going to get what you want. Your code will compile whatever I ask the return type to be, but will fail at runtime if the type isn't compatible.

Try it out:

```
String s = makeObject("java.lang.String"); // compiles and runs
Integer i = makeObject("java.lang.String"); // compiles but fails at runtime with java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

A safe version would look like that

```
static <T> T makeObject(Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
    return clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
}
```

but that suggests you already know what type you want to have instead of just getting a class name from a file or something.

Comment: The type will not compatible with what? I dont use casting anyware.

Comment: `return (T)c.cast(object);` <- that is a cast.

Comment: Due to type erasure, the simple fact of creating a generic method adds an implicit cast to the generic type. See here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html